# @After method being run first by JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4, spring-junit

I am running into a strange issue with my JUnit test case: the `@After` method is invoked first by JUnit.

Here is the abstract class I use for my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { TestServicePlusRepositoryIntegrationConfiguration.class })
@ActiveProfiles(Profiles.TEST)
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractServicePlusRepositoryIntegrationTest {

}
```

Here is the problematic test case:

```
public class AdvertisementServiceSecurityTest extends AbstractServicePlusRepositoryIntegrationTest {
...

@Before
    public void setUp() {
        advertisement = advertisementFactory.createAdvertisement(OWNER_OF_ADVERTISEMENT_EMAIL);
        impersonator = memberFactory.createMember(IMPERSONATOR_EMAIL, Role.ROLE_BASIC_CHILDCAREWORKER);
        when(geolocationServiceMock.retrieveAddressFromReference("valid-reference")).thenReturn(new Address());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {//Executed first!
        advertisementFactory.deleteAdvertisement(advertisement);
        memberFactory.deleteMember(impersonator);
    }

...

@Test(expected = AccessDeniedException.class)
    @WithUserDetails(IMPERSONATOR_EMAIL)
    public void deleteAdvertisementByIdWithInvalidMember() {
        advertisementService.deleteAdvertisement(advertisement.getId());
    }
```

What could cause the `@After` method to run first? FYI, I don't use JUnit 3.

Here is the full source code for the test case: https://gist.github.com/balteo/e8c2ea96db22d3f9c88e

Comment: Can you explain why you believe this method is being executed before the test cases?

Comment: I have added three breakpoints: a first one in the setup method a second one in the teardown and a third one in the test method. The first breakpoint that gets hit is the teardown one...

Comment: Could you provide a complete runnable example (say with System.out statements) that demonstrated the behavior?

Comment: @JohnB: I am in the process of doing so. Bear with me a while please...

Comment: @JohnB: I have put together a somewhat trimmed-down example that demonstrates the issue. How can I share it with you?

Comment: Would it be possible to share it with you in a private way because although it is trimmed down, most of my production code is left there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears an exception was raised in the `@Before` method causing it not to complete:

```
2014-11-08 13:39:12.169  WARN 4513 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@44c03695] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void com.bignibou.it.service.advertisement.AdvertisementServiceSecurityTest.deleteAdvertisementByIdWithInvalidMember()] for test instance [com.bignibou.it.service.advertisement.AdvertisementServiceSecurityTest@49438269]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(value=joe.hacker@gmail.com)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: Username: joe.hacker@gmail.com not found!
    at com.bignibou.service.security.MemberUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MemberUserDetailsService.java:22)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:36)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:82)
    ... 24 common frames omitted

tearDown
```

Using Spring's `@BeforeTransaction` see javadocs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/BeforeTransaction.html) allowed the test to run and pass:

```
@BeforeTransaction
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("setUp");
        advertisement = advertisementFactory.createAdvertisement(OWNER_OF_ADVERTISEMENT_EMAIL);
        impersonator = memberFactory.createMember(IMPERSONATOR_EMAIL, Role.ROLE_BASIC_CHILDCAREWORKER);
        when(geolocationServiceMock.retrieveAddressFromReference("valid-reference")).thenReturn(new Address());
    }

    @AfterTransaction
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("tearDown");
        advertisementFactory.deleteAdvertisement(advertisement);
        memberFactory.deleteMember(impersonator);
    }
```